# Why does the history command do nothing in a script file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-history

If I create a file containing

```
 #!/bin/bash 
 history
```

and run it, I get no output. Running it manually in a terminal or `source`ing the script file *does* produce output.

Why does `history` not work from a file?

Comment: For better understanding I changed the question..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The second command does "work", but the history is not enabled for non-interactive shells which is why it returns nothing in your script.

Testing the default in a non-interactive shell:

`nohistory.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o | grep history
history
```

Result:

```
$ ./nohistory.sh
history         off
```

Enabling history with `set -o history`:

`history.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o history
set -o | grep history
history
```

Result:

```
$ ./history.sh
history         on
    1  set -o | grep history
    2  history
```

Comment: How do you then get the script to read your bash_history?